# How to populate a grid row just by clicking a tree element?

Tags: gridview, tree, treeview, dhtmlx

I have dhtmlx Tree in a division. And a dhtmlxGrid in another division.

**Now, I want to click an element in that tree and the grid row should automatically get populated by value of that element.**

How to do That ??

Comment: You can use events to do that, but since your question is too vague, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set double or single click event handler on tree like below:

```
myTree.setOnDblClickHandler(loadMyGrid);

function loadMyGrid(treeNodeId){
    myGrid.clearAll();
    myGrid.load("URL_TO_YOUR_PAGE?tid="+treeNodeId);
}
```

In above example double clicking on tree node will call loadMyGrid function passing in node id that you may use to call your server page passing in node id from tree.
For more information on how to setup tree or grid using dhtmlxSuite you may check their documentation at http://docs.dhtmlx.com/